# Jquery SelectBoxIt: bold option text?

Tags: jquery

Has anyone tried using [this script](http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/index.html) to show some option text in bold font?

I want something like this.
Is that possible?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is.
Just apply the style **font-weight:bold** to the `<option>`

```
<select>
  <option disabled selected>Select one</option>
  <option style="font-weight:bold">Bolded</option>
  <option>Not bolded</option>
</select>
```

And with SelectBoxIt: http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/index.html#HTMLOptionSupport